# How to configure Mule ESB (mule.bat) with different Java Version?

Tags: java, mule

I have four JDK installed on my system for multiple modules.

jdk1.8.0_25, 
jdk1.7.0_75 and 
jdk1.6.0_19

I want to configure or change Mule.bat so that it should pick default Java version different from what set in Java home.

Following is code of Mule.bat but i am not able to find Java Home parameter in it.

```
@echo off setlocal

rem Copyright (c) 1999, 2006 Tanuki Software Inc. rem rem Java Service Wrapper command based script rem

if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" goto nt echo This script only works with NT-based versions of Windows. goto :eof

:nt

rem rem Find the application home. rem rem %~dp0 is location of current script under NT set _REALPATH=%~dp0

rem ############################################################### rem Customized for Mule rem
###############################################################

rem Make sure that MULE_HOME is set. If no value was set in the environment, rem use the path that was used to launch this script. Since this script rem resides in the bin folder of the Mule distribution, we need to cut off the rem last 5 chars (\bin\) from the real path to determine the proper MULE_HOME if "%MULE_HOME%" == "" set MULE_HOME=%_REALPATH:~0,-5% echo MULE_HOME is set to %MULE_HOME%

rem If MULE_BASE is not set, set it to MULE_HOME if "%MULE_BASE%" == "" SET MULE_BASE=%MULE_HOME%

if "%MULE_APP%" == "" (
    set MULE_APP=mule ) if "%MULE_APP_LONG%" == "" (
    set MULE_APP_LONG=Mule )

set PATH=%PATH%;%MULE_HOME%\lib\native\profiler set
_WRAPPER_BASE=%MULE_HOME%\lib\boot\exec\wrapper

rem Configure remote Java debugging options here rem Setting suspend=y will wait for you to connect before proceeding set JPDA_OPTS=-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005

rem ############################################################### rem Decide on the wrapper binary. set
_WRAPPER_EXE=%_WRAPPER_BASE%-windows-x86-32.exe if exist "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" goto validate set
_WRAPPER_EXE=%_WRAPPER_BASE%-windows-x86-64.exe if exist "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" goto validate set _WRAPPER_EXE=%_WRAPPER_BASE%.exe if exist "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" goto validate echo Unable to locate a Wrapper executable using any of the following names: echo %_WRAPPER_BASE%-windows-x86-32.exe echo %_WRAPPER_BASE%-windows-x86-64.exe echo %_WRAPPER_BASE%.exe pause goto :eof

:validate rem Find the requested command. for /F %%v in ('echo %1^|findstr "^console$ ^start$ ^pause$ ^resume$ ^stop$ ^restart$ ^install$ ^remove"') do call :exec set COMMAND=%%v

if "%COMMAND%" == "" (
    rem ###############################################################
    rem Customized for Mule
    rem ###############################################################
    echo Running in console/foreground mode by default, use Ctrl-C to exit...
    set COMMAND=:console
    rem pause
    rem goto :eof
    rem ############################################################### ) else (
    shift )

rem rem Find the wrapper.conf rem :conf set
_WRAPPER_CONF="%_REALPATH%..\conf\wrapper.conf"

rem ############################################################### rem Customized for Mule rem
###############################################################

rem add XML compatibility jars set MULE_ENDORSED=-M-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%MULE_HOME%\lib\endorsed

rem Mule options: Set the working directory to the current one and pass all command-line rem options (-config, -builder, etc.) straight through to the main() method. set MULE_OPTS=set.MULE_APP=%MULE_APP% set.MULE_APP_LONG=%MULE_APP_LONG% set.MULE_HOME="%MULE_HOME%" set.MULE_BASE="%MULE_BASE%" set.MULE_LIB=%MULE_LIB% wrapper.working.dir="%CD%" wrapper.app.parameter.1=%1 wrapper.app.parameter.2=%2  wrapper.app.parameter.3=%3  wrapper.app.parameter.4=%4  wrapper.app.parameter.5=%5  wrapper.app.parameter.6=%6  wrapper.app.parameter.7=%7  wrapper.app.parameter.8=%8 wrapper.app.parameter.9=%9

rem Adding additional jvm arguments to wrapper configuration if needed call "%MULE_HOME%\bin\launcher.bat" "%MULE_HOME%\bin\additional.groovy" %_WRAPPER_CONF% "%JPDA_OPTS%" "%MULE_ENDORSED%" %*

if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto run goto :eof

:run

rem ############################################################### rem rem Run the application. rem At runtime, the current directory will be that of wrapper.exe rem call :%COMMAND% if errorlevel 1 pause goto :eof

rem ############################################################### rem Customized for Mule rem
###############################################################

:console "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" -c %_WRAPPER_CONF% %MULE_OPTS% goto :eof

:start "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" -t %_WRAPPER_CONF% %MULE_OPTS% goto :eof

:pause "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" -a %_WRAPPER_CONF% %MULE_OPTS% goto :eof

:resume "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" -e %_WRAPPER_CONF% %MULE_OPTS% goto :eof

:stop "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" -p %_WRAPPER_CONF% %MULE_OPTS% goto :eof

:install "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" -i %_WRAPPER_CONF% %MULE_OPTS% goto :eof

:remove "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" -r %_WRAPPER_CONF% %MULE_OPTS% goto :eof

rem ###############################################################

:restart call :stop call :start goto :eof

:exec %* goto :eof
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mule uses the Java Service Wrapper to control the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) from your native OS.

1) You need to make changes to wrapper.conf file:-

> $MULE_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf

2) Then you need to set **wrapper.java.command** parameter in it,

> wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java

or

> wrapper.java.command=c:/jdk1.6.0/bin/java

JAVA_HOME

Comment: Thanks. I was not hit with this that i can give full path there. :)
It saves lot of effort. :)