# How to change Mule ESB (mule.bat) with different Java Version?

Tags: java, mule, mulesoft, mule-esb

I want to change java version in mule standalone server that means different java version from what set in Java home. I have referred example [How to configure Mule ESB (mule.bat) with different Java Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699667/how-to-configure-mule-esb-mule-bat-with-different-java-version) but I'm still getting an error. Please help.

I have added specified java version in wrapper.java.command as per example but still referring to java home version not specified wrapper.conf file.

Appreciate your help.

Mule Version : 3.9.4
confg/wrapper.conf
Under Wrapper Properties
wrapper.java.command=C:/java/jdk8u262/bin/java

I didn't change mule.bat.

Comment: Don't modify the mule.bat or mule.sh. Please share the change you did, the Java path in your system, and the version of Mule.

Comment: Updated mule version in Question section.

Comment: When you execute exactly the same path from the command line, does it work?

Comment: Regards my previous question, you may need to change the slash character `/` to backlash `\` to make it work in the command line.

Comment: you mean C:\java\jdk8u262\bin\java instead of C:/java/jdk8u262/bin/java ?

Comment: Yes, in the command line, not in wrapper.conf. Depends on what shell you are using to execute the commands, Powershell or cmd.exe.